# In PHP is there a way to cache full objects and get references to those?

Tags: php, caching

As an example:

In case of `apc_store($key,$value)` it serializes the value when stored into memory. And `$value=apc_fetch($key)` copies and then de-serializes the value when fetched.

I need to access a periodically-refreshed copy of a large data structure (1MB or so) without incurring the penalty of copying the data structure, and de-serializing it in PHP, but could not find any cache in php suitable to do this.

Is there a way in a PHP webservice to share a datastructure (arrays objects etc.) between processes, without incurring the cost of copying etc.?

Comment: Sounds like a good use for a database.

Comment: There is no way of storing an object between requests without serializing/deserializing; because PHP isn't persistent like java